# Convert Large String Number to Number

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this string

```
let a = '1589480087711852280'
```

How do I convert this to a number?

If I do

```
let a = '1589480087711852280'
a = Number(a)
console.log(a)
```

It prints `1589480087711852300` and just rounds it.

How do I get it to print `1589480087711852280`?

It tried BigInt and that just puts an n at the end of the number.

I'm using this to query within mongodb so its not pulling the right search.

Comment: BigInt is the right way to go. The `n` is fine, if you need to interact with it numerically, use other BigInts with it.

Comment: Like @CertainPerformance said, you need to use BigInt.
`let a = BigInt('1589480087711852280')`
BigInt is similar to Number, but it can't be used with methods in Math and can't be mixed with instances of Number. Be careful when casting because BigInt precision may be lost when it is coerced to a Number.

Comment: Thanks this prints as `1589480087711852280n` How do I get it as a number `1589480087711852280`? I want to be able to use this in a MongoDB query so the `n` causes issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```
let a = '1589480087711852280'
a = BigInt(a)
console.log(a + 1n) // 1589480087711852281n
```

Comment: This prints as `1589480087711852280n`

How do I get it as a number `1589480087711852280`?

Comment: You have to work with `BigInt` since the number doesn't fit in the range of `Number`.

Comment: Convert the result back to a string because you started with a number in a string format!